# How to exit on double back press with showing the snackbar dialogue of exit?

Tags: android, android-intent, onbackpressed, android-snackbar

I wanted to make a snackbar dialog on double press to exit...(java)

**Requested with these**

1. On 1st time back pressed show dialogue " press back again to exit " for 2 seconds
2. On pressing back again show "do you want to exit ? " with the
   confirmation button for 2 seconds

**As like below -**

[image]

Comment: @Zoe Thank you, ill take care of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create id for your layout in activity_main

```
CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {     
    coordinatorLayout= (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout);
if (!doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
            Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "Do you really want to exit?", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("YES", new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //button action here
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }).setActionTextColor(Color.YELLOW)
              .show();
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
                }
            }, 2000);
        }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You supposed to be kidding me, That was the kotlin syntax and was 100% right.

Comment: I had asked for java.

Comment: did you mentioned that anywhere? nowadays, kotlin is used most for android development.

Comment: No problem. :) i will approach you working with kotlin, it is lot more better with threads.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for you -

```
private final long DOUBLE_PRESS_BACK_TO_EXIT_TIME = 2000;
boolean doubleBackPressed = false;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // todo: show the snackbar here. 
        this.doubleBackPressed = true;
        utils.showToastLong(getString(R.string.press_again_to_exit));
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackPressed = false;
                // todo: hide the snackbar here. 
            }
        }, DOUBLE_PRESS_BACK_TO_EXIT_TIME);

    }
```

To customize the Snackbar you may follow this [link](https://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-snackbar-example/)